# How to increase the stability of a DAE solver?

Tags: pde, stability, differential-equations, method-of-lines, dae

I am trying to solve a set of linear PDEs of the form
$$F\left(\vec{y},\frac{\partial \vec{y}}{\partial x},\frac{\partial^2 \vec{y}}{\partial x^2},\frac{\partial \vec{y}}{\partial t}\right)=0.$$
To solve it I am using the method of lines where I discretize in $x$ to get a set of differential-algebraic equations (DAEs) which I solve using the IDA solver shown in [this tutorial](https://jmodelica.org/assimulo/tutorial_imp.html). It seems to be working okay, however, it is highly numerically unstable. I find that if I set `atol=rtol=1e-1`then the code works okay. If I reduce the error tolerance anymore the solution blows up to infinity. Do you know how I can increase stability? I am very new to solving DAEs so any advice is appreciated.

Edit:

The equations are given, here:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -\left[i\omega b + ik_\perp v - \sin\alpha\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right],$$
$$\frac{\partial b}{\partial t} = -\frac{i}{\omega}\left[\cos^2\alpha\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\omega^2u}{v_A^2(x,t)}\right],$$
$$\cos^2\alpha\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\omega^2v}{v_A^2(x,t)}=i\omega\left[ik_\perp b - \sin\alpha\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}\right],$$
where
$$\vec{y}(x,t)=\begin{pmatrix}
u(x,t) \\
b(x,t) \\
v(x,t)
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Is your DAE index-1?  Is the initial condition consistent with the algebraic constraints?

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the equations I am solving. I am new to DAEs, these equations seem too complicated to calculate the index?

Comment: Looks like using solvers from the SUNDIALS package for an ideal MHD problem. However some time derivatives have become $i \omega$ and some have not - is this correct? Can the third equation be cast in a time-evolution form, like the first two?

Comment: Yes, this does come from an MHD problem. Here $t$ does not represent time, it actually represents a spatial coordinate. I used $t$ for this post to make it clear which variable I am integrating in and which variable I am discretizing in. Traditionally, $t$ is the coordinate which is integrated over with the method of lines.